# How to open a windows file from a python shell

Tags: python, path, python-unicode

I am new to python. i have tried all the techniques available in tutorials and textbooks to open an already existing file through the python shell, it always return one form of error or the other.

```
test_file = open('C:\Users\User\Documents\test.txt')
```

> **Copy comment**:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module> 
>   see_file = open('Arrows') 
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Arrows' 
>
> test_file = open('C:\Users\User\Documents\test.txt') 
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
> ```

Comment: *"FileNotFoundError:"*: Your file `'Arrows'` have probably a extension like `'.JPG'` or isn't in the **Current Working Directory**.

Comment: Yes, it has an extension '.py'. But it is in the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, i have now resolved the issues

Answer (score 0):

```py
file_open = open('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\test.txt')
```

This should do the trick, You need to escape special characters like `\` with `\`

Answer (score 0):

If by opening you mean loading a file:

```
path = "C:/Users/User/Documents/test.txt"
file = open(path, 'r')
```